# Can you boot a BootCamp disk from another machine on one that never used BC before?

Tags: bootcamp

I have a 128GB SSD from a decommissioned MacPro3,1 that had a Boot Camp installation of Windows 10. That disk has sat in a drawer for the last 4 years and now I'm trying to see if I can boot up that Windows installation on a 2018 Mac Mini. I have an external USB 3 SATA device which I've plugged the SSD into and I can see the BOOTCAMP volume on the macOS Sonoma desktop. Unfortunately, holding down the <kbd>Option</kbd> key at boot time only shows the Mini's "Macintosh HD" by itself; I expected that it would detect the Windows SSD and display it as an option.

Is there something that needs to be set on the Mini to allow the BOOTCAMP volume to be seen in the boot options menu? NVRAM perhaps? I always thought that since I could plug in a USB stick and boot through the <kbd>Option</kbd> menu, just plugging this old BOOTCAMP drive in would just work, but alas...

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the answer to all of your questions is no. Windows probably was set up to BIOS boot, which cannot be done on a 2018 Mac mini because there is no BIOS in the firmware. If there are no UEFI boot files, then I suppose you could add them. However, this would require converting the existing MBR partition map to a GUID partition map and there may not be space on the drive for the GPT.

You may be able to use a virtual machine to BIOS boot the Windows installation. For example, VirtualBox can create virtual machines where entire physical drives can be part of the virtual machine hardware.

If you do get Windows to boot, then Windows will have to adapt to the new hardware configuration. Whether Windows can succeed at do this remains to be seen.